# Changed LWJGL icon not staying the same after export through JARSPLICE (Java)

Tags: java, icons, export, lwjgl

I've got a problem with changing the taskbar icon in LWJGL after exporting to a runnable program. Changing the icon in the debug mode is not a problem.

I can change the icon like so:

```
Display.setIcon(loadIcon("src/com/root/game/res/favicon.png"));

private static ByteBuffer[] byteBufferArray;
private static BufferedImage bufferedImage;
private static ImageIOImageData imageIOdata;

private static ByteBuffer[] loadIcon(String path) {
    imageIOdata = new ImageIOImageData();
    try {
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        byteBufferArray = new ByteBuffer[] {imageIOdata.imageToByteBuffer(bufferedImage, false, false, null)};
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteBufferArray;
}
```

After doing all of that, the icon indeed changes.
The problem is, that after I actually export the program to .jar file and subsequently export the program to a new runnable .jar file with all the native libraries and needed .jar files through a program called Jarsplice, the icon changes back to the default LWJGL icon, as if I didn't even change it in the first place.

Could someone please give me a tip or preferably a solution to how I could make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your src folder doesn't get exported to the jar file? You should better put your resources in a separate res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the logo is in a folder. Then right click the project and go to build path > configure build path. Then go to the libraries tab and either click on add class folder if the folder is in the project or add external class folder if the folder is somewhere else on your drive. Then navigate to the folder containing the logo and click ok. After you've done that try exporting again and see how it goes :)